# Menu not functioning properly

Tags: html, css

Alright, I have some questions...

When you have a moment, can you take a look at http://www.crystalcoach.com/new

I'm having some trouble with the hover menu. Okay, I know it's probably a super out of date code... But it works, haha.

What I'm having difficulty with (and see image for examples) is when you hover over the menu, the positioning is wrong. If you go to the URL above and hover over a menu, you'll see what I mean.

In addition, where in the code can I change it so the menus are wider? If you hover over "Fleet", you'll see that the menu itself is not wide enough to encompass all of the vehicles in there. I had to abbreviate a few but the hover portion isn't fully working.

Thanks so much for your help.

Here's the image: http://i1166.photobucket.com/albums/q617/stevezee87/menusample.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, its old alright, messy too, but here's what you need to change:

**1)**

There is a `div` being presented with the sub-menu options. That `div` contains a `width` of `150px`, loose that declaration and the sub-menu will grow according to its contents!

The mentioned `div` is right after the `<a></a>` with the menu text:

[image]

---

**2)**

The `span.qmritem` needs to have a `top` value just about `10px` by my tests, to keep in line regarding the non-hovered menu options.

---

**3)**

The `div` mentioned at point **1)**, must get those same `10px` increase on the existent `top` value:

[image]

---

**Link to both images in full size:**

[Screen-shot for Problem 01](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10760661/a_crystal_coach_css_problem_01.jpg)

[Screen-shot for Problem 02/03](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/76169930/stackoverflow/question/10760661/a_crystal_coach_css_problem_02.jpg)